# Finding keys having value greater than 2

Tags: r, string

- I have a key value pair as below which is in form of string

  ```
   > data$Frequency  

  1  A1:6,B1:4,AA1:3   
  2  BB1:2,AAA1:1  
  3  BBB1:1,A2:1,C2:3  
  4  D1:1  
   > class(data$Frequency)
     "character"

  FreqIndex<-which(colnames(data)=="Frequency")
  freq_string<-paste(as.character(unlist(data[FreqIndex])),collapse=",")
  print(freq_string)

  >"A1:6,B1:4,AA1:3,BB1:2,AAA1:1,BBB1:1,A2:1,C2:3,D1:1"
  ```
- How can i find keys which have value greater than 2

  ```
  A1,B1,AA1,C2
  ```

Comment: Did you meant `unlist(lapply(strsplit(data$Frequency, ","), function(x) sub(":\\d+", "", x[as.numeric(str_extract(x, "(?<=:)\\d+"))>2])))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another variation of `strsplit` where we split by `:` or `,`, then assuming that there are always key/value pairs, use the logical index recycling to subset the numeric values, check whether it is greater than 2 and subset the non-numeric elements

```
v1 <- unlist(strsplit(data$Frequency, "[:,]"))
v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)][as.numeric(v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)]) >2]
#[1] "A1"  "B1"  "AA1" "C2"
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse` options

```
library(tidyverse)
filtered <- data %>%
              separate_rows(Frequency, sep=",") %>%
              separate(Frequency, into = c('group', 'freq'), convert = TRUE) %>% 
              filter(freq>2) %>% 
              pull(group)
filtered
#[1] "A1"  "B1"  "AA1" "C2" 

condition <- paste(shQuote(filtered, type="cmd"), collapse=", ")
condition
#[1] "\"A1\" , \"B1\" , \"AA1\" ,\"C2\""
```

Comment: Error in strsplit(data$Frequency, "[:,]") : non-character argument

Comment: @Akki `strsplit` takes `character` class.  If you have a `factor` column, convert to `character` i.e. `strsplit(as.character(data$Frequency), "[:,]")`

Comment: @Akki There is `convert` argument.  Forgot about it earlier which will convert it to `integer` class

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- "A1:6,B1:4,AA1:3,BB1:2,AAA1:1,BBB1:1,A2:1,C2:3,D1:1" #create the string
y <- sapply(strsplit(x, ","), strsplit, ":") #split the string into single keys and values

dat <- data.frame(key = rep(NA, 9), value = rep(NA, 9)) #prepare empty dataframe

## fill dataframe
for(i in 1:length(y)){
  dat[i, 1] <- y[[i]][1]
  dat[i, 2] <- y[[i]][2]
}
```

gives you

```
> dat
   key value
1   A1     6
2   B1     4
3  AA1     3
4  BB1     2
5 AAA1     1
6 BBB1     1
7   A2     1
8   C2     3
9   D1     1
```

and now `dat$key[dat$value > 2]` gives you

```
> dat$key[dat$value > 2]
[1] "A1"  "B1"  "AA1" "C2"
```